# From element inside a document is not known with Safari when there is frameset element

Tags: html

With Safari when trying this line of code : document.main it gives undefined  but When I remove the frameset it works without any problem

With IE I have no problem at all

Would you please advise ?

```
<form id="main" name="main">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input type='hidden' name='LANGUAGE' value='<%= pageLanguage %>'>
<input type='hidden' name='userType' value='<%= user.getType() %>'>
</body>
<frameset cols="20, *" frameborder=0 >
    <frame src="include/blankpage.html" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 noresize>
    <frame src="documents/ListConfidentialDocuments.jsp" name="frmList" id="frmList"  frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 noresize >
</frameset>
</form>
```

th

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking a bit messed up.

Firstly, you're either using a frameset or you're not. You can't have a frameset and body content also, you need to decide which one you're using.

Having said that, the form you've got (if you decide to use a frameset) would go in one of the frames.

I think you probably need to spend a bit of time learning HTML. A document should only contain one `body` tagset and everything that's being displayed on the page need to go inside of that, forms included.

Personally I'd think about re-writing this, put your form inside the body, and consider using iframes (if you must do it using frames atall).

```
<body>
<form [...]>
    <input type='hidden' name='LANGUAGE' value='<%= pageLanguage %>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='userType' value='<%= user.getType() %>'>
</form>
<iframe src="include/blankpage.html" [...]>
<iframe src="documents/ListConfidentialDocuments.jsp" [...]>
</body>
```

The main reason i think you're encountering problems is that your HTML is a mess. Browsers are usually quite good at figuring out what you *meant* to do however in this circumstance I think Safari is just unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the element with `name=main` is a `<form>`, `document.forms.main` should work. As you also included `id`, calling `document.getElementById('main')` will work, too.

However, your markup is wrong and illogical. Why do you include the `<form>` to a document where it will never be seen because the frames are present? You shouldn't use frames at all; if you have to, please learn the basics of HTML. DOM tree for HTML document with frameset + fallback for browsers that don't support frames should look like:

```
html
|__head
|   |__title
|__frameset
    |__frame
    |__frame
    |__noframes
        |__body //this is fallback content
            |__form (or anything else)
```

As @Jamie mentioned, you might want to use iframes.

Comment: still not working 'always undefined ' with safari the 'document.main'

Answer (score 0):

The markup given isn't valid HTML. Validate your markup at [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) & you will know the problems. Fix those & everythingone would work cross browser.

Lastly, you might want to start using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS%3F)

Comment: <frameset cols="20, *" frameborder=0 >
 <frame src="include/blankpage.html" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 noresize>
  <frame src="documents/ListConfidentialDocuments.jsp" name="frmList" id="frmList"  frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 noresize >
</frameset>
<NOFRAMES>
<BODY>
<form id="main" name="main">
<input type='hidden' name='LANGUAGE' value='<%= pageLanguage %>'>
<input type='hidden' name='userType' value='<%= user.getType() %>'>
</form>
</BODY>
</NOFRAMES>